# 2018 January Challenge: Geometry

Tags: geometry, triangle

Considering it's the beginning of a new year, I have created the following challenge. I hope to make one every month until December 2018!

Here goes:

> [image]
>
> Show that $AD-AB>AC^3$. Do not use scale drawings.

Note that this post was advised to be migrated to Puzzling Stack Exchange from Mathematics.

Comment: the diagram given seems sufficient to give precise lengths for every line segment, so the lengths can be resolved to surds and the inequality proven that way,

Comment: @Jasen are you assuming DC is parallel to the bottom segment?

Comment: @boboquack Yes. I was. Oops!

Comment: @boboquack but if it's not disproof is trivial. it sure looks like AD−AB can be made negative.